# How to make this code run in modern nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, logging, websocket

I am trying to implement a simple web interface where I can see do tail -f of my log file.

Found the below link

https://thoughtbot.com/blog/real-time-online-activity-monitor-example-with-node-js-and-websocket

It seems to be very old and not compatible with modern-day `node.j`.

I tried to go through node.j` documentation but was unable to fix this. 
Child process creation is causing some issues.

```
var filename = process.argv[2];

if (!filename)
  return sys.puts("Usage: node watcher.js filename");

var tail = process.createChildProcess("tail", ["-f", filename]);
console.log("start tailing");

tail.addListener("output", function (data) {
  console(data);
});


var http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.sendHeader(200,{"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  tail.addListener("output", function (data) {
    res.sendBody(data);
  });
}).listen(8000);
```

I want to send this tailf'd log to another server, which will be running nodejs app to read this.
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I've searched through the whole nodejs documentation, but I haven't found any version where there were `process.createChildProcess()`.

However, you can replace it using the `child-process` built-in module:

```js
const filename = process.argv[2];

if (!filename){
  console.log("Usage: node watcher.js filename");
  process.exit(0)
}

const child = require('child-process')

const tail = child.exec("tail", ["-f", filename],{shell:true});
console.log("start tailing");

tail.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});


const http = require("http");
http.createServer(function(req,res){
  res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  tail.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    res.write(data);
  });
}).listen(8000);
```